# Redirect to change pass page for users with expired password

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have web app with spring security. Now I am trying force user to change expired password.

My security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserService service;
    CustomAuthenticationHandler customAuthenticationHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/s/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/changePassword").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .failureHandler(customAuthenticationHandler)
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth
        .authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/s/**");
    }

    // Beans    

    @Bean
    CustomAuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(new UserDetailServiceImpl(service));
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
}
```

My CustomAuthenticationHandler :

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // later do some logic here.. to handle CredentialsExpiredException 
        // for now all failure login should go to /changePassword
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/changePassword");

    }
}
```

I expect go to /changePassword after login failed , but I still going to /login?error. 
Can you suggest example for this task with java config or explaning what I am doing wrong? 
All help appreciated

Comment: From: [CRYPTO-GRAM](https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram/archives/2017/1015.html#2) by Bruce Schneier:
        
NIST recently published its four-volume SP800-63-3 Digital Identity Guidelines. Among other things, it makes three **important suggestions** when it comes to passwords:

*Stop it with password expiration. That was an old idea for an old way we used computers. Today, don't make people change their passwords unless there's indication of compromise.* Password expiration ends up with users choosing poor passwords, people only have a finite number of good passwords.

Comment: @zaph yeah but in this task, I do not decide how it should be

Comment: @zaph I agree, although in a scenario where the password is reset by an administrator, forcing the user to pick up a new password replacing the one provided is still a valid use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know how good or bad this solution, but it works for me

Security Config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserService service;
    CustomAuthenticationHandler customAuthenticationHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/s/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/changePassword").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .failureHandler(customAuthenticationHandler)
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth
        .authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/s/**");
    }

    // Beans    

    @Bean
    CustomAuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(new UserDetailServiceImpl(service));
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
}
```

My CustomAuthenticationHandler :

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        setUseForward(true);
        saveException(request, exception);
        if (exception.getClass().equals(CredentialsExpiredException.class)){
            setDefaultFailureUrl("/changePassword");                  
        } else {
            setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error");
        }
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }

}
```